# How to select distinct max value from multiple join table MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my current query for selecting data:

```
select a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara, c.ID_Rad, d.ID_Lab
FROM tb_registrasi a 
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
    ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
JOIN tb_radiologi c
    ON a.No_Registrasi = c.No_Registrasi
JOIN tb_laboratorium d
    ON a.No_Registrasi = d.No_Registrasi
```

And here's the result: 
[image: query result]

How do i distinct those ID_Rad and ID_Lab and I need the max value from each ID_Rad and ID_Lab so it will be like this:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`, try this;)

```
select a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara, CONCAT('RA-', MAX(substring(c.ID_Rad, 4) + 0)) AS ID_Rad, CONCAT('Lab-',MAX(substring(d.ID_Lab, 5) + 0)) AS Id_Lab
FROM tb_registrasi a 
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
    ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
JOIN tb_radiologi c
    ON a.No_Registrasi = c.No_Registrasi
JOIN tb_laboratorium d
    ON a.No_Registrasi = d.No_Registrasi
GROUP BY a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara
```

Comment: And what about `RA-11` for example ?

Comment: @sagi Hmm, U R right, thanks for your catching, updated.

Comment: I think you will also need to convert the number into an integer, since `'2'` is bigger then `'11'`

Comment: @sagi Yes, absolutely right, `substring(c.ID_Rad, 4) + 0` this is converter.

Comment: Didn't notice that