# MySQL not returning null column joined value

Tags: mysql

I have these 4 tables:
[image: tables]


My expected result: 
[image: expected result]

this my current query (helped from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408182/how-to-select-distinct-max-value-from-multiple-join-table-mysql/37408251#37408251))

```
select a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara, CONCAT('RA-', MAX(substring(c.ID_Rad, 4) + 0)) AS ID_Rad, CONCAT('Lab-',MAX(substring(d.ID_Lab, 5) + 0)) AS Id_Lab
FROM tb_registrasi a 
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
    ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
JOIN tb_radiologi c
   ON a.No_Registrasi = c.No_Registrasi
JOIN tb_laboratorium d
   ON a.No_Registrasi = d.No_Registrasi
GROUP BY a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara
```

this the result from the query:
[image]

how do i get the result that im expecting for? I'm really unexperienced in advanced query like this, any help is very much apreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Change your joins to `LEFT JOINS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
select a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara, CONCAT('RA-', MAX(substring(c.ID_Rad, 4) + 0)) AS ID_Rad, CONCAT('Lab-',MAX(substring(d.ID_Lab, 5) + 0)) AS Id_Lab
FROM tb_registrasi a 
LEFT JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
    ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
LEFT JOIN tb_radiologi c
   ON a.No_Registrasi = c.No_Registrasi
LEFT JOIN tb_laboratorium d
   ON a.No_Registrasi = d.No_Registrasi
GROUP BY a.No_Registrasi, a.Nama_CTKI, b.Nama_Negara
```